# Java Array Index Out of Bounds Exception in For-loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am making a program that runs a formula on the numbers inputted. The first integer in the input describes the amount of lines, or integers to be used in the formula. I am approaching this by calculating the answers and pushing them into an array. However, I am getting an array out of bounds exception in one of my for loops, and I can't figure out why.

Here is my main method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    int[] nums = {};
    int lines = scan.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
        nums[i] = potFormula(scan.next());
    }
    System.out.println(nums);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to initialize the nums array to the length of lines

Comment: As an aside, once you fix the array issue, you'll find that your print statement doesn't do what you want. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array

Answer (score 4):

Arrays have a fixed size that can't be changed once allocated. You're initializing `nums` to `{}`, which is an empty array. Its size will always be zero.

Instead, you could use:

```
int lines = scanner.nextInt();
int[] nums = new int[lines];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your array is too small (it has zero elements). Here is one way to fix this:

```
int lines = scan.nextInt();
int[] nums = new int[lines];
```

This approach works since you know the size in advance. If you didn't, you could use an `ArrayList<Integer>`. Array lists have the ability to grow on demand.

Comment: plus 1 for mentioning ArrayList!

Comment: @HaifengZhang although since the number of items is known in advance, an ArrayList might just be unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the nums array to the length of the lines,

Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    int lines = scan.nextInt();
    int[] nums = new int[lines];
    for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
        nums[i] = potFormula(scan.next());
    }
    System.out.println(nums);
}
```